# I want to save this whole array as log file on codeigniter

Tags: xml, codeigniter

I want to save this whole xml response array as log file on .txt or .xml file on codeigniter? Different file name like filename with date and time?

```
    Array ( 
    [xmlmsg] => 
    <Message date="06/05/2018 18:36:39">
    <Version>1.0</Version>
    <OrderID>12279</OrderID>
    <TransactionType>Purchase</TransactionType>
    <PAN></PAN>
    <PurchaseAmount>200</PurchaseAmount>
    <Currency>524</Currency>
    <TranDateTime>06/05/2018 18:36:39</TranDateTime>
    <ResponseCode></ResponseCode>
    <ResponseDescription></ResponseDescription>
    <Brand></Brand>
    <OrderStatus>CANCELED</OrderStatus>
    <ApprovalCode></ApprovalCode>
    <AcqFee>0</AcqFee>
    <OrderDescription>For booking-200 hour yoga teacher training</OrderDescription>
    <ApprovalCodeScr></ApprovalCodeScr>
    <PurchaseAmountScr>2,00</PurchaseAmountScr>
    <CurrencyScr>524</CurrencyScr>
    <OrderStatusScr>CANCELED</OrderStatusScr></Message> )
```

Comment: You should include what you have tried, not just what your question is

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html#log_message

Comment: ...or don't respond... that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the CI docs has all the info you need:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html#write_file

```
$this->load->helper('file');
if ( ! write_file('./path/to/file.xml', $data['xmlmsg']))
{
        echo 'Unable to write the file';
}
else
{
        echo 'File written!';
}
```

(where `$data` is your array).